# Glide doesn't set GlideDrawable into ImageView after loading image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I'm loading images using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) this way in a `Fragment`

```
Glide.with(this).load(pictureUrl)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.default)
        .into(image);
```

but the image is never set into the `ImageView` although the image IS indeed being loaded (I investigated this using a listener). I believe this only happens  when the image is not being loaded from memory since it does load if the `Fragment` is resumed.

If I add `asBitmap()` above, then the image successfully loads. Also, setting the `GlideDrawable` into the `ImageView` from an attached `RequestListener`'s `onResourceReady()` method also works.

Comment: I am interested what you changed in your custom ImageView, what was causing this issue? (i see you commented on the discussion list that you fixed the issue but didnt post how actually  :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with a similar problem, it turned out to be related to a custom View. See [the post on the discussion list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/glidelibrary/PFHIu2ebMbg) for more information.

Comment: What was causing the issue in the custom view?

Comment: Have same issue with custom view... can u tell what is causing the issue in custom ImageView ??